# Finding 2 numerical strings on same line

Tags: search, find, notepad++

I am new to Notepad++ and have ben researching how to do this, but it seems each answer I try to mimic doesn't work correctly.

Here is the scenario:

I have 2 text files, each with ATM transactions such as time of transaction (In military time, such as 18:09) and transaction amount (Displayed as 43.00)

I need to find a way to search the document so that it only returns matches where both the time and amount are there, and on the same line of the document.

Example would be, I need to find on this huge text file where both 43.00 and 18:09 appear on the same line, allowing my to verify the transaction was valid.

Any ideas on how to do this?  I am using the latest Notepad++6.8 and have downloaded the compare plugin.

Thank you and I will begin researching how the coding works in notepad++ in the meantime, as I am not an experienced programmer (Just had 1 college course in C++ which I loved but eh)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-F, Select "Regular expression" as Search mode and then write:

> 8:09.*43.00

Comment: You are the man, thank you!  Im new to these forums so I tried going you +1 or whatever.  When im able to I will come back and bump you, thanks again mate

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl F, search for 43.00 or 18:09.

Comment: If I do that, I end up with hundreds of results on the document.  Searching for the 2 strings to be on the same line would narrow that down to (Hopefully) just 1 results.  For instance, if the line in the document reads like this  xxxxxx   18:09    xxxx   xx   xxxx   43.00     I would need to do a search that pulls back that 18:09 and 43.00 only when they appear on the same line.  Thanks